# Whether to average two groups and analyse calculations from averages or should all analyses include all baseline data from each individual?

Tags: observational-study

I have followed two groups and measured a number of variables. Some of the variables can be used to calculate new measures. Is it ok to average the two groups and analyse calculations from the averages (ie each group acting as a single entity to provide a new measurement) with separate tests or should all the analyses include all the baseline data from each individual?

Comment: What you should do depends on what you want to find out.

Comment: Firstly, I want to find out if the two groups are acting similarly through time and if I can combine their information. Secondly I want to analyse their mean values as groups and new measurements caculated using these means (if this is statistically sound) to assess what is going on through time also.

Comment: Clarify this with context.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify you have individual variables that roll up into a new variable? Such as food satisfaction and wait staff satisfaction rolling up into one new variable called dining satisfaction ( food sat + staff sat = dining sat).

If you are only inferring/comparing group 1 to group 2 based on the new variable, the individuals ones are not helpful, that is unless of course you are interested in examining the correlation of these variables. The usefulness of the correlation depends on how the weighing or how the final variable is calculated. For example if food sat can only be up to 30% and staff sat can only be up to 70% of the calculation for dining sat.

Determining the proper statistical tests to compare the groups depends on the test’s individual assumptions being met. Are you comparing two unpaired or paired groups and is the distribution normal (gaussian)? You could employ a t-test or z-test to compare the means of the two groups and determine whether the differences can be explained by
probability alone.

You can use the T-test as long as the following assumptions are met.

1. Groups must be independent
2. Sample size from the two groups may or may not be equal
3. Standard deviation thus variance is the same

If all (1-3) of the assumptions are met, we can use the standard student’s t-test. If only 1-2 are met we can use Welch’s t-test.

You can also use an F-Test if you want to assess the variance of the two groups per  assumption 3 before proceeding. This test strictly requires that the distributions be normal. If you are not able to transform your data to normal or simply want to use the data as is, Levene’s test (i.e., absolute values of the deviations from the mean) and the Brown-Forsythe test (i.e., absolute values of the deviations from the median) would be more robust.